# How to use the secret uri to get the secret value stored in the azure keyvault?

Tags: azure, pfx, secret-key, azure-keyvault, azure-resource-manager

By using the ARM API's I am able to fetch the secret uri of the secret stored in azure keyvault

```
 https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mySubID}/resourceGroups/{myResourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{myvaultName}/secrets/{mycert}?api-version=2015-06-01
```

But I wanted a secret value to form a PFX cert inorder to upload to a service.

How can I achieve this ?

Please help !! Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
GET https://{vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}?api-version={api-version}
```

Refernce: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret

**NOTE:**

I was not successful with this in the beginning, later found out that I was using the token obtained from 
 `https://management.core.windows.net`

Apparently it failed saying like `InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience :The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource`

**So remember you have to get the token from 
`https://vault.azure.net`**

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted a secret value to form a PFX cert inorder to upload to a service.

We could do that with the following API.

```
Get https://{Secret Identifier}?api-version=2016-10-01
```

More details please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecrets). About authentication please refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/authentication--requests-and-responses).

> **Note**: The authority for a request to a Key Vault is always as follows, `https://vault.azure.net/`

We could get the Secret Identifier from you mentioned API. We also could get it from Azure portal.

[image]

I test it on my side it works correctly on my side. More details please refer to the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I used a PowerShell script similar to below to get a KeyVault secret value.  Great Q and Great A (not mine, those).  In case it's not clear the AZ command is part of the Azure CLI.

```
$keyvaultToken = (az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net) | ConvertFrom-Json
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "$($keyvaultToken.tokenType) $($keyvaultToken.accessToken)"}
$resp = iwr -uri https://vaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretName/secretVersion?api-version=2016-10-01 -Headers $headers
$json = $resp.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.value
```